# Removing Event Listeners in my AS3 Preloader

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, preloader

So far, I have managed to build a simple text based preloader in which I can load external SWF files. I have a lot of prebuilt SWFs and loading them externally seems to be the best option. I have managed to get my preloader to work, however I want to remove my event listeners and the loader child once the event is completed. Please could someone take a look at my code and explain what i've done wrong.

Thank You very much,

Luke

```
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("gallery.swf");
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
var finishLoading:Loader = new Loader();

finishLoading.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, done);
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, fileLoaded);
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, preload);
loader.load(req);

function fileLoaded(event:Event):void
{
        addChild(loader);
}

function preload(event:ProgressEvent):void
{
    var percent:Number = Math.round(event.bytesLoaded / event.bytesTotal * 100);           //this gives a percent of how much data has been loaded
    preload_txt.text = String(percent) + "%";
}

function done(event:ProgressEvent):void
{
    if(event.bytesLoaded >= event.bytesTotal){
        removeChild(loader); 
        loader = null;

        loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, fileLoaded);
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, preload);
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You garbage collected the loader before removing the event listeners.. reverse it.

```
if(event.bytesLoaded >= event.bytesTotal){
  loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, fileLoaded);
  loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, preload);
  removeChild(loader); 
  loader = null;
}
```

Comment: doh! that makes sense. Relatively new to AS3. Thank you for your very fast response!

Comment: Accept this answer if it fits to your needs!